# Ionic 3 - Deep Linking - URL Not Appearing

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

Trying to use the new deep linking system using the @Page decorator.

I think I have everything set up correctly (no errors showing in the console) but the URL's are not appearing. Here's my code

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePageModule } from '../pages/home/home.module';
import { JobsPageModule } from '../pages/jobs/jobs.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HomePageModule,
    JobsPageModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    SplashScreen,
    StatusBar
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({
    name: 'home',
  segment: 'home'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }


}
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "0.0.12",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "0.0.6",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "someProject: An Ionic project"
}
```

Any advice would be great.

UPDATE:

Found this link

https://github.com/fundo90/ionic2-starter-mobile/tree/b53023d99e78e7b2b56ff4345555656b2de743b7/src

Which seems to have the URLs. But unsure as to how he is importing the modules

Answer (score 7):

Ok doke so figured it out from the following tutorial

http://masteringionic2.com/blog/2017-04-14-lazy-loading-and-deep-linking-with-ionic-3/

So, in app.component.ts need to remove the following import

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
```

And then when setting the root page, we use the name we created using the ionic page decorator i.e

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'home',
  segment: 'home'
})
```

So app.component will look like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';


    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    export class MyApp {
      rootPage:any = 'home';

      constructor(
        platform: Platform,
        private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
        private statusBar: StatusBar
       ) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
          // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
          // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
          this.statusBar.styleDefault();
          this.splashScreen.hide();
        });
      }
    }
```

And we don't need to import the modules as I have done in my question above. So app.moudule.ts will look like this

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    SplashScreen,
    StatusBar
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hope that helps somebody!

Comment: have you also found that if you open an unknown route the rootpage opens but the address bar is not updated?

Comment: You are right Sam , have you found any solution for it?

Comment: I am try to entry url in chrome but not working. can anyone tell me how to generate url

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HomePageModule } from '../pages/home/home.module';
import { JobsPageModule } from '../pages/jobs/jobs.module';
```

You do not need to import these two pages, since in your `home.module.ts` and `jobs.module.ts` already defined the imports. See if removing those will help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have menu in my page which is causing issue. I just moved menu to app.html and it works.